# Can I use Firebase "in-app-purchase" event to handle Purchases safely

Tags: firebase, in-app-purchase, firebase-analytics

i have a Question about how Firebase handles the in-app-purchase Event, so i can know if it ise usable for Handling purchases.

My Questions are:

1. Does this work on the Client?

   ```
   FirebaseAnalytics.LogEvent("in-app-purchase");
   ```

   If yes,
2. How can I validate this data on the server (Cloud Functions), so that I can secure this process, so that I can be sure that every purchase is valid?

If the in-app-purchase event is not safe, how can i use an other option and which?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Short answer is no, the Firebase analytics event is not a validation that a real purchase was made. If you have subscription IAPs then it will be wildly inaccurate as well. The correct way to validate a purchase was made is through server-side receipt validation.

Comment: So, i can use this event and than validate it server-side?

Comment: @FelixO. This event does not provide enough information to validate purchase. BTW, It's reported automatically (by gms?) and in my experience it's not tricked by client-side IAPs hacking. I do have custom event I sent when user completes purchase - and `in-app-purchase` does not include those hacked receipts. For proper validation you need server-side real-time notifications (https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/realtime_developer_notifications) and client "registration" - to link specific client to it's server-side processed purchase